# Is there a way to insert/embed CARTO maps in a Streamlit app?

Tags: python, streamlit, cartodb

I wish to know whether there is any way to place/insert/embed an interactive CARTO map in a Python Streamlit App by any means.

I have access to my CARTO's account API key if that could help.

Thus far, I have not found any information regarding the topic, so if anyone knows anything about this, it'd be hugely appreciated.